# Форма обратной связи работает только с временной почтой, но не с моей личной

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

прошу подсказать возможные причины, если адрес моей почты введен абсолютно правильно

```
 <form action="mail.php" class="form">
                    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
        <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="AdvantageCard">
        <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="MyMail@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Заявка">
        <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

              <textarea name="Text" class="messange__input" placeholder="Ваш текст" ></textarea>
              <input name="Phone" data-tel-input type="text" class="phone__input" placeholder="Ваш контакт" autocomplete="off" >
              <p class="form__text">*Мы никому не передаем ваши данные. </p>
              <button type="submit" class="form__btn">Отправить</button>
            </form>     
    
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
 
//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;
mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );    

//js

$(document).ready(function() {

    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос php-код, который отвечает за отправку сообщений

Comment: Скорее всего, неправильно настроен SMTP. Посмотрите этот вопрос -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532486/failed-to-connect-to-mailserver-at-localhost-port-25

Comment: @DanSazonov Возможно вы можете предоставить решение, ибо с моими знаниями php мне только убиться с решением

Comment: а что за временная почта, в чем ее временность? `MyMail@gmail.com` - это временная или личная? и где вы проверяете? спам-папки смотрели?

Comment: @Arbery
временная почта эта почта которая создается на разных спец сайтах на небольшое время, обычно около 10 минут, после чего она самоуничтожается, такую почту обычно используют для проверок. MyMail@gmail.com я просто обозначил место де вписывается почта

Answer (score 1):

Для решения проблемы было необходимо подключить DKIM и DMARC для почтового ящика